configure xcode script for unity build (in Teamcity based on User-defined Parameters)
I have a Unity project with a version parameter (env.BUILD_TYPE = CH or INT) passed through User-defined Parameters in Teamcity.
The task should configure xcode workspace:
In Targets -> Unity-IPhone -> Signing & Capabilities:
Add Associated Domains:
For INT version: applinks:mapp.onelink.me
For CH version: applinks:lapp.onelink.me
Enable Background Modes with Remote Notifications, Game Center, In-App Purchase, Push Notifications, and Sign in with Apple
Set Project Format to XCode 15.0
In UnityFramework -> Build Settings -> Other Linker Flags, add flag -ld_classic
In UnityFramework -> Build Phases -> AuthenticationServices.Framework, change from Required to Optional
In Project -> Unity-IPhone -> Info:
Set Localizations to English, French, German, Italian, Portuguese (Brazil), Russian, and Spanish
For CH version, add to Info.plist:
NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription and NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription with a specific string
NSUserTrackingUsageDescription with a specific string
Add icons for A/B testing: images/a.png, images/b.png, images/c.png, images/d.png
Can anyone help me write this Swift script? Or how make this with scripting (python priority), without GUI?
